Getting error while generating Defog Schema
I am trying to connect to the defog server using the command:

defog gen table1

I am getting below error:
    D:\>defog gen table1
    Do you want to automatically scan these tables to determine which column might be categorical? The distinct values in each column likely to be a categorical column will be sent to our server. (y/n)
    n
    Getting schema for the relevant table in your database...
    We got an error!
    Error message: Something went wrong. Please try again later.
    Please feel free to open a github issue at https://github.com/defog-ai/defog-python if this a generic library issue, or email support@defog.ai.
    Your schema has been generated and is available at the following CSV file in this folder:
    
    D:\/None
    
    We are now uploading this auto-generated schema to Defog.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts\defog.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\defog\cli.py", line 43, in main
        gen()
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\defog\cli.py", line 327, in gen
        df.update_db_schema(filename)
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\defog\admin_methods.py", line 11, in update_db_schema
        schema_df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv).fillna("")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 948, in read_csv
        return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 611, in _read
        parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1448, in __init__
        self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1705, in _make_engine
        self.handles = get_handle(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 718, in get_handle
        ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 460, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
        raise ValueError(msg)
    ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>


Any suggestions?
